# Showing a sequence is in $l^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $ (y_n)_{n\ge0}$ be a given sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.
>   If for every $x = (x_n)_{n\ge0} \in \ell^1,$  the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_nx_n < \infty,$$ show that $y \in \ell^\infty$.

I am trying to show that $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty |y_nx_n| =\sup \|y_n\| $$  by associating a linear functional defined for $x_n$ in $\ell^1$, am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

If $y\notin\ell^{\infty}$, so that $y$ is unbounded, then you can extract a subsequence $(y_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ such that $y_{n_k}>k$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$ (or $y_{n_k}<-k$, which case is analogous). Define $$x_n\equiv\begin{cases} 1/k^2&\text{if $n=n_k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$},\\0&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ Then, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\ell^1$, as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1/k^2=\pi^2/6$. But $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y_n x_n\geq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}=\infty.$$